# knockoutjs calling function which is defined in sub-viewModel from root-viewModel

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, root, subview

I have a single page application with structure:

- ViewModel-RootVM (page header, footer, common functions, ...):

  - SubModelA (page1 - template)
  - SubModelB (page2 - template)

I would like to call a function fnTest which is defined on page 2 (SubModelB) from page header (ViewModel-RootVM). How can I do that from ViewModel and from HTML? Is this even possible? If so, please help me with an example. I'm a little lost here.

I'm using knockoutjs v2.2.1 and jQuery v1.9.1

**ViewModel** (you can see the rest of the code in jsfiddle, link below)

```
var View = function(title, templateName, data) {
        var self = this;


    self.title = title;
    self.templateName = templateName;
    self.data = data;

    self.myPostProcessingLogic = function(element1, index1, data1) {
        console.log('post processing');
    };
};

var SubModelA = function(root) {
    var self = this;

    self.items = ko.observableArray([
        { id: 1, name: "one" },
        { id: 2, name: "two" },
        { id: 3, name: "three" }
      ]);
};

var SubModelB = function(root) {
    var self = this;

    self.firstName = ko.observable("Bob");
    self.lastName = ko.observable("Smith");

    self.fnTest = function() {
        alert('calling function from subModelB');
    };

    self.fnSubModelB = function() {
        root.allert('calling function allert from root');
    };
};

var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.views = ko.observableArray([
        new View("one", "oneTmpl", new SubModelA(self)),
        new View("two", "twoTmpl", new SubModelB(self))
        ]);

    // default open page 'two'
    self.selectedView = ko.observable(self.views()[1]);

    self.allert = function() {
        alert('alert from rootVM');
    };

    self.allert2 = function() {
        // how can I call function 'fnTest' which is defined in SubModelB
        self.views()[1].fnTest(); // this is not working
    };
};

var viewModel = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

[link to jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jqWizard/vxLjP/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not working because fnTest() is not declared in the "View", but in its "data". It works using:

```
self.views()[1].data.fnTest()
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/LJBqp/

Comment: juhuhu, you just made my day. Thank you!